# Get data from Firebase which contains all specified items in 'array'

Tags: firebase, where-clause

I have a structure like this:

```
users
 - user1
    - name: 'Bob'
    - age: 25
    - posts
       - bobPost1
          - text: 'Lorem ipsum...'
          - tags
            - web: true
            - programming: true
            - school: true
       - bobPost2
          - text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor...'
          - tags
            - web: true
            - design: true
            - school: true
       - bobPost3
          - text: 'Sample text...'
          - tags
            - web: true
            - programming: true
```

I want to retrieve all Bob's posts by tags. For example 'web' and 'school'. Result should by post1 and post2. 
Is possible to achieve this just with firebase or should I get all his posts and then filter them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to get a data snapshot of the entire `post` no matter what, but luckily that is not a lot of data to worry about.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/users/user1/posts");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
    // Gets everything under "posts", iterates each post
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        // "bobpost1", "bobpost2", etc
        var key = childSnapshot.key();
        // Data underneath bobpost#
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();

        // Iterates through tags
        for(i in childData.tags) {
            // Do/check something
            // If post contains all specified tags, then store key somewhere
        }
    });
});
```

You iterate through all the post using `forEach` and then you save the name of the post inside `key` and the data inside `childData`.

`childData` will look like:

```
- text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor...'
- tags
    - web: true
    - design: true
    - school: true
```

Then iterate through `tags` with a regular JavaScript for each loop doing some check. I advise storing the `key` inside an array if all the tags are found or whatever you are checking for.

**Remember that the Firebase call is asynchronous and the data won't always be ready after the `.once` call. Perform all actions inside the call back.**

[Firebase | forEach](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/foreach.html)